# Open UDP Ports 1024 and above

Tags: port-forwarding

I've got a device which the manufacturer suggests:

> Usually, no port configuration is really necessary. You just have to
>   make sure that all UDP ports above 1024 are not being blocked. If it
>   still doesn’t work, please create additionally a port forwarding for
>   the ports 9573 & 3478, both UDP.

How can I do that on my Dlink 655?

I have to mention that if I connect that device on my ISP's modem that has all ports open on LAN1 the device connects to the manufacturer's portal. Behind my router, not.

Comment: [How to open a port on the D-Link DIR-655](https://portforward.com/d-link/dir-655/)

Comment: I know how to open ports David. But here its says "You just have to make sure that all UDP ports above 1024 are not being blocked" Whats the range of that though.

Comment: Just do the second bit. "please create additionally a port forwarding for the ports 9573 & 3478, both UDP."

Comment: I did but it does not working

Comment: <shrug> I don't have any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue at the end. What I did was to port forward all the **UDP ports (1024-65535)** on the device's IP. Disable the **SIP** on my firewall because I was seeing a lot of SIP blocked packets in my logs. And also changing the **NAT Endpoint Filtering** for **UDP** packets from **Address Restricted** to **Endpoint Independent**. I don't know if I'm at risk, with those changes, but my device now sees the outside world. By making those changes doesn't mean I know what I actually did. So I would appreciate if anyone can explain to me what exactly I did there

Comment: What do you mean you disabled the SIP?

Comment: On my Firewall settings under APPLICATION LEVEL GATEWAY (ALG) CONFIGURATION I unchecked the SIP option.

Comment: On the D-Link? It's pretty unclear what exactly you did on which device. But I guess it's nice that it's working now. As for the forward you will have a hard time receiving UDP connections on your other devices as you pretty much exclusively redirect and traffic for ports about 1024 to that "device" (whatever it might be).